# How to install SQL Server Management Objects

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database, sql-server-express

After performing a reinstall of my system, I'm trying to take a copy of a database using a SQL Azure Batch Backup tool. Also, I have SQL Server 2016 SP1 Express installed.

However, when I try to run the backup tool it tells me

> Error message = Could not load file or assembly
>   'Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The
>   system cannot find the file specified..

After some googling I found out that `Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo` is one of the *SQL Server Management Objects*. Fine. Understandably this wouldn't be installed with SQL Express. So can I install this on its own?

[Apparently](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/installing-smo) "If you want to ensure that SQL Server Management Objects is installed on a computer that will run your application, you can use the Shared Management Objects .msi in the [SQL Server feature pack](https://www.microsoft.com/download/details.aspx?id=52676)."

So I followed that link to a page which offers me 6 different .msi downloads, none of which have anything like "shared management objects" or "sql server feature pack" in the name.

Can anyone point me in the direction of an installer which will install these *SQL Server Management Objects*, compatible with SQL Server 2016 SP1 Express?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you scroll down the download list, you will see more downloads and "ENU\x64\SharedManagementObjects.msi".

Comment: You're absolutely right. I found that out several days ago and really should have come back to update my post. Thanks for posting.

Answer (score 1):

I found `SQLSysClrTypes.msi` & `SharedManagementObjects.msi` [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=103444)

Answer (score 0):

To restore a bacpac created on SQL Azure to your local SQL Server Express instance, please download the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio, then download the bacpac to your PC, after that follow the steps provided on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-tier-applications/import-a-bacpac-file-to-create-a-new-user-database) article.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo